# Could not load compiled classes for settings file 'E:\AccuRide\android\settings.gradle' from cache. > settings_93vy294g361sk31a5mzzi6mpx

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, npm

When I using the command `react-native run-android` to build the project on the device.
It is starting the metro server but when it is going to install the app, it throws an error that

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
  Connecting to Daemon
* What went wrong:
Could not load compiled classes for settings file 'E:\AccuRide\android\settings.gradle' from cache.
> settings_93vy294g361sk31a5mzzi6mpx

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not load compiled classes for settings file 'E:\AccuRide\android\settings.gradle' from cache.
> settings_93vy294g361sk31a5mzzi6mpx

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

    at makeError (E:\AccuRide\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at E:\AccuRide\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (E:\AccuRide\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (E:\AccuRide\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! AccuRide@0.0.1 android: `react-native run-android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the AccuRide@0.0.1 android script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Office\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-13T13_05_21_430Z-debug.log
```

Here, is the log C:\Users\Office\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-12-13T13_05_21_430Z-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'android'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.12
3 info using node@v14.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'preandroid', 'android', 'postandroid' ]
5 info lifecycle AccuRide@0.0.1a~preandroid: AccuRide@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle AccuRide@0.0.1~android: AccuRide@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle AccuRide@0.0.1~android: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle AccuRide@0.0.1~android: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;E:\AccuRide\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Office\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator;C:\Users\Office\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\bin;C:\Users\Office\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Office\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Office\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Office\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;
9 verbose lifecycle AccuRide@0.0.1~android: CWD: E:\AccuRide
10 silly lifecycle AccuRide@0.0.1~android: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-native run-android' ]
11 silly lifecycle AccuRide@0.0.1~android: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle AccuRide@0.0.1~android: Failed to exec android script
13 verbose stack Error: AccuRide@0.0.1 android: `react-native run-android`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid AccuRide@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd E:\AccuRide
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "android"
18 verbose node v14.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.12
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error AccuRide@0.0.1 android: `react-native run-android`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the AccuRide@0.0.1 android script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I Uninstall the project and reinstalled it, but still shows the error.

Please help me. I can't understand how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to be of help you should upload your `settings.gradle`

In the meanwhile, you might check wether you have all your dependencies (for example, before autolinking was a thing, some dependencies asked you to add extra lines to that file).

As it seems you are in Windows, check if your paths in that file are forwardslashes rather than backslashes.

https://aboutreact.com/could-not-compile-settings-file/

However, I'm shooting in the dark right now.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem after clearing the cache,

Fixed it by deleting the `.gradle` folder inside the project folder and restarting android studio
fixed the issue